# Run Visual Studio debugger in a loop until a breakpoint is hit?

Tags: windows, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-debugging

Is there a way to repeatedly debug a program with Visual Studio until a breakpoint is hit?

I have a program that usually runs to completion but occasionally hits a certain (error) branch. **I want to re-run the program in the debugger until that branch is taken** (i.e. a breakpoint is hit) or maybe until an exception is triggered.

Is there a way to do this with the Visual Studio debugger? (Either in the UI or via a script.)

Comment: Did you find a way to do this? I guess there is no command line api for visual studio debugger. I have done this with WinDbg successfully though.

Comment: @QutabQuazi No, unfortunately not.